# What other thing i can use except array here?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, sequence

is there any way to get rid of arrays in this program? Im not allowed to do it with `std::array` or `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int upper,i,j=0,k=0;
    int arr1[1000],arr2[1000];
    cout<<"Enter the upper bound :";
    cin>>upper;
    for(i=0 ; i<upper ; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            arr1[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr2[k] = i;
            k++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"List of even numbers :";
    for(i = 0; i<j ; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr1[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"List of odd numbers :";
    for(i = 0; i<k ; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr2[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::vector sounds like a good choice

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention but both vectors and arrays arent allowed

Comment: What is even going on here? There's no comments in the code, and no explanation as to what you're doing. Are you just printing a bunch of even numbers, and then a bunch of odd ones? If so the arrays don't seem to serve any useful purpose. You could write two loops to do the same.

Comment: Hint: To skip over numbers use `i += 2` in your loops.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting elements of two arrays just output at first even numbers in the given range and then odd numbers.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter the upper bound: " ;

    unsigned int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    std::cout << "List of even numbers :";
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i += 2 )
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    std::cout << "List of odd numbers :";
    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i += 2 )
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the upper bound: 10
List of even numbers :0 2 4 6 8 
List of odd numbers :1 3 5 7 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll not analyze the rest of your code but focus on the question:

> is there any way to get rid of arrays in this program?

Since you can't use `std::vector<int>` you could allocate the memory dynamically yourself.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    size_t upper;

    std::cout << "Enter the upper bound :";
    if(not (std::cin >> upper)) return 1; // input failed, exit

    // create unique_ptr<int[]> poiting to an array of "upper" number of elements:
    auto arr1 = std::make_unique<int[]>(upper);
    auto arr2 = std::make_unique<int[]>(upper);

    // ...
```

Comment: He said vectors aren't allowed.

Comment: @user10191234 Oh, I only saw arrays in the question. Good catch

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{ 
int upper;

std::cout << "Enter the upper bound :";
std::cin >> upper;
std::cout<<"List of even numbers :";
for (int i=0; i<upper;i+=2)
   std::cout <<i<<" ";
std::cout <<"\n";
std::cout<<"List of odd numbers :";
for (int i=1; i<upper;i+=2)
   std::cout <<i<<" ";

return 0;
```

}